# UITableView vs UiScrollView qual e a melhor opção - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Ola, tenho a seguinte duvida, tem algum problema (e uma boa pratica) eu usar uma UiTableView para criar o layout dos meus apps ou seria mais recomendado eu usar uma UiView com uma UiScrollView, considerando que esses layout podem ou não conter campos de input como textfields,campo de data.... etc

Obs: Estou criando meus layouts programaticamente

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende da tela, se for uma tela em que nada se repete, é preferível utilizar uma scrollview. Mas se for uma tela de cadastro, por exemplo, que vários itens se repetem, tableview ou colection view é mais aconselhada e até mais fácil de fazer.

Comment: Opa foi o que estava pensando, vlws pela resposta